# suitability for stringstream in parsing text files

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to write a lexer (i.e. separate tokens in a text file) and then build a parser on top of it. I've been studying compilers for some time and I'm wondering how should I go to write the lexer part: I've only used stringstream to process simple input.. since this time the amount of data could be a lot I'm asking if stringstream could work for a lexer.

I'm asking this since it seems quite slow to set up, quite limited in its capabilities for a parser.

Comment: I find it's better to read text into a std::string via std::getline and then parse it. It seems hard to have fine grain control with std::stringstream.

Comment: @AnonMail reading the characters one by one and putting them in the current token (until it terminates and/or an invalid character is found), right?

Comment: Correct.  Your lexer would usually just read character by character.  I would wrap your character stream so the lexer doesn't know the implementation.  And I would use std::getline as mentioned.

Comment: I would add, can't you use something implemented already (e.g. boost Spirit)?  Or are you required to write the lexer.

Comment: @AnonMail the language is kinda easy to parse and I've never used spirit. I believe it might be overkill for this project and I might spend more time learning how to use it properly rather than writing the actual logic

Comment: @AnonMail I forgot to mention: the language is stack-based in reverse notation (like `10 4 add`). It shouldn't be too hard to parse, that's why I kinda discarded spirit in the first place.

Comment: @AnonMail a small insight into suitability of boost spirit for this one (plus what you already wrote) and I'll accept this as an answer. Works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the suitability of `Spirit` depends on the size of your project.  If it's a small lexer and parser then it may not make sense.  But if it's a complicated language, it will make sense since you can worry about implementing the functionality of the language as opposed to writing the lexer and the parser for it.